# Sync 6th generation iPod nano with iCloud Music Library

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-music, ipod-nano

I have a 6th generation iPod nano wit 8GB memory and I've recently subscribed to Apple Music.
Whenever I sync my iPod with iTunes I get this error message:

[image: Error message]

But in the iPod settings I can't find any "iCloud Music Library" to turn on. Also all the songs I would like to synchronize have already been downloaded locally on my PC.

I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Songs from Apple Music (as in your iCloud Music Library) can only be used with iOS devices, Android phones and computers running macOS or Windows.

From [apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204839#add), emphasis mine:

> Before you can download music to listen to offline, you need to add the songs, albums, or playlists to your Library. Then, in the Music app on your **iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch**; in iTunes on your **Mac or PC**; or in the Apple Music app on your **Android phone**, find the song, album, or playlist that you want to download, and follow these steps: (...)